# While using splice and slice in array from where to start cout on string i am little bit confuse about it?

Tags: slice, splice

> While using splice and slice in array from where to start cout on
> string i am little bit confuse about it?

ex:
`const array=["mango","orange","pineapple","watermelon"];
for splice or slice method from where should start  count ?

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens? Also, which programming language do you use? Please edit your question to contain more details

Comment: i tried it still have confusion..your advice does not work !

Comment: "your advice does not work" - what do you mean by that? Please edit your question to contain more details